# Reference for Multivariate Taylors theorem on closed domains

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, taylor-expansion

I'm currently looking for a source (preferably a book) that provides a proof of the multivariate Taylors Theorem in the setting that a function $f$ is defined on a closed domain $D$ and is $m$-times continuously differentiable in the interior of the domain such that all partial derivatives extend continuously to $D$.

The univariate case can be found [here](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1516/math1010c/Taylor.pdf), but I am particularly interested in a quality reference (book) of the multivariate case.

Comment: Let me share some thoughts with hope it possibly helps: Taylors Theorem is known for open convex set. If all derivatives are continuous and we can continuosly extend them on closure of set, then they should be uniformly continuous. Now thinking reverse - if all functions in Taylors Theorem are uniformly continuous on open set, then we can continuosly extend them on closure and we get Taylors Theorem on closed set.

Comment: @zkutch Does this imply more than the equivalence of the desired theorem and a theorem for open sets and uniformly continuous derivatives?

Comment: Yes, seems it turns out that way. If you find it helpful I can bring more bases for suggested argumentation as answer. But I did not understand well  the turn of speech "more than the equivalence" - what you mean under "more"?

Comment: @zkutch With 'more' I mean that this is not really answering the question in the sense that it's neither a reference nor a proof, right? I was just not sure whether I was missing something. But if I understand the comment correctly, it just gives an equivalence formulation to help the search.

Comment: I agree! Suppose you have the TT (or this generalized Role's theorem from your reference) for every pair from the interior. Then taking limit "should" give the analogue for pairs one or both of which are on the boundary.